# Has any sci fi ever tried to explain how conservation of momentum and energy would work with time travel or other similar teleportations?

Tags: time-travel, teleportation

Where one just shows up in one point in time and space, whether through time travel or teleportation (one may argue any teleportation would involve time travel due to space-time relativity, but I think what's being asked is clear enough), has anyone ever tried to explain the conservation of energy and momentum in such scenarios?

Comment: In Discworld, if you teleport across the disk you keep moving against the spin.  I'll have to look up which book mentions this.

Comment: If memory serves, there's a debate between two characters about the implications of time travel for conservation laws in _The Time Ships_ by Stephen Baxter. (It's an authorized sequel to _The Time Machine_ by H G Wells, published to commemorate the novella's centenary.)

Comment: I’m reminded of the scene in the JJ Abrams Star Trek where Kirk is beamed up from free-fall and cracks the transporter pad as he materialises.

Comment: Neal Asher's polity novels involve gates called Runcibles that enable FTL travel. Serious heatsinks are required to bleed off the excess energy of those arriving, assuming the survival of the arrivee and the city they're arriving in is desired. Some plots use this "fact" to enable the creation of weapons or commit terrorist attacks.

Comment: (backward) time travel already requires somehow hand-waving away all of known physics. Going from there to matching movement frames with the target ground doesn't seem like it would take more than an extra bit of pinky waving. Remember that every object in the universe has a speed *relative to other objects*. There's no absolute speed.

Comment: @Chenmunka It was *Interesting Times*. The position of Rincewind is exchanged with a large cannon in the hopes that the large mass would reduce the velocity it would have in order to maintain momentum.

Comment: Does a Stargate count as a teleporter?

Comment: @Chenmunka probably *Interesting Times* - there are a couple of incidents in the book where something is teleported and arrives at high speed (Rincewind in a snowdrift near the start, and an unknown creature from XXXX ending up rather worse for wear at the end).

Comment: I've been reading SF for nearly 60 years and never once met that idea.

Can you say why conservation of energy or momentum might matter in such scenarios?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I have a feeling your SF wasn't hard enough ;D If you teleport into a car, why would you move as fast as the car? *BTW* the question is *too broad* - Has any sci fi ever tried to explain that? As mentioned, even fantasy did try, and SF... more time you could count.

Comment: @Mithoron - I wanted to write that SG-1 would be like "hold my beer" - because transport involves molecular deconstruction, so you just emerge at the other end always within that destination system's relative movement system. Frame dragging at the edge of any solar system seems to be a big thing, so it's not a trivial question, and I disagree it's to broad. Ok, maybe a little bit. Anyway, molecular deconstruction and conversion to a energy stream seems to be the trick that solves the problem. Even for teleporters. But then again  it is a bit murky when SG:A's puddle jumpers come play...

Comment: @AcePL Minor correction, but Stargates don't convert to an energy stream, just a matter stream; that's how Sam accidentally infected a sun in "Red Sky", for example. Also I think DKNguyen was talking about how Stargates preserve the input momentum relative to the gate of whatever goes in? It was talked about in "Upgrades" just before the team superspeed-ran through the gate to take out the Jaffa on the other side.

Comment: @Idran I do not accept the correction...  Maybe just in part. Stargate converts whatever it sends into subatomic particles. Depending on which particles exactly, the distinction between matter and energy is murky, true... However, considering that objects are buffered in the DOD and there is nothing about matter compression in the Stargate technology, I'd lean towards energy. Transportation rings are using matter stream, true, but it's not exactly the same tech as gates.

Comment: Mithoron, you might have studied 7 times more SF than I, and all  three times 'harder' and then the more so, how did you not long ago meet an Answer to this Question?

When you ask D about teleporting into a car, is your real query whether you'd be travelling as fast as the car at the moment of teleportation?

Then why not first explain how 'teleportation' works for you, and why it allows spacial precision enough to hit the car seat, but fails to account for speed or time? 

When fantasy did try, and SF more time you could count, why not Post a few examples?

Comment: If someone knows how to make this question acceptable, feel free.

Comment: It's a bit late now, but asking for the first instance of such a thing, and using the [tag:history-of] tag would have made this question well-scoped and on-topic.

Answer (score 17):

Larry Niven's teleportation stories, beginning with the hard-to-find ["By Mind Alone"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54152) (1966) (about psychic teleportation) and his ["Flash Crowd"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Crowd) series (technological teleportation) all deal with issues of energy and momentum conservation.  Niven wrote a non-fiction piece ["The Theory and Practice of Teleportation"](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?115990) in 1969 as well; here's a link to Niven presenting the material that would later show up in that [article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDRvhBU3oKE).

In the stories, characters suffer disaster when they carry momentum from one reference frame to another (don't teleport out of a moving car), or people develop "momentum dampers" to balance out a large number of people's (technological) teleportations; energy conservation can result in overheating (as gravitational potential energy is converted to heat).

Quote from "By Mind Alone"

> Pat would be all right. But Larsen was in for a surprise. We wouldn’t
> be changing any laws of physics. **What Pat had run into was the law of
> Conservation of Energy. In teleporting a mile downhill she’d lost a
> good deal of potential energy. She’d gotten it back in heat: about
> seven degrees per mile.**
>
> **And if that law held, so did conservation of momentum.**
>
> Some cops came along and pried me out of the car. A doctor told me how
> lucky I was, and I believed him, because all I had was two cracked
> ribs and four teeth knocked out on the steering wheel, which is why my
> smile today is so even and bright.
>
> The next morning Larsen visited me at the hospital. He told me about
> Carol.
>
> She’d teleported home. She’d appeared in the middle of her bedroom,
> four feet from a startled maid. The maid was in the hospital,
> suffering from shock.
>
> Last night a jerking muscle woke me up to catch myself whispering,
> “Carol, come back. Come back.” I hope she doesn’t. **It’s been six years
> since she rammed into a bedroom wall at sixty miles per hour, without
> even a seat belt to protect her.** If she came back now, she’d be
> breaking another of God’s marvelously consistent laws. And you can’t
> do that.

Comment: I recall a similar short story, (Asimov, one of his one or two pagers???), whose title I can't recall or figure out about a pair of scientists who test their teleportation vehicle only to find themselves in a completely empty void.  They quickly figure out that they accounted for the motions of the planet, star, and galaxy through space, but they didn't account for the motion of our universe through a greater medium still and have stepped out of it entirely.  Now they're a perturbation in an otherwise high density universe and ... big bang.  Sorry for the lack of detail re: origin.  I tried.

Comment: Didn't Niven have a (brief) description of a large mass in one of the Great Lakes that served as the excess energy/momentum sink for the teleport network?

Comment: Yes he did.  Will update to clarify

Comment: Niven's later Ringworld books included teleportation on the Ringworld.  Teleporting in a straight line from one edge to the other had no problems, but moving any significant distance spinward or antispinward resulted in too high a difference in relative velocity that could not be compensated for.

Comment: @Jason Patterson That puts me in mind of Isaac Asimov's [Blank!](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68265), but it's only a partial match: it is a (very) short story, it does feature two scientists travelling in a machine, which has to account for the motion of the Earth, and they do find themselves in a void; but it's a time machine not a teleporter, their mistake is different (with no mention of a high-density medium), and their fate is rather less spectacular.

Answer (score 8):

One milieu that is worked out paying fairly close attention to conservation laws with respect to teleportation is the world of Qish in the stories "Displaced Person" and "Captives of the Slavestone" (both 1987) by Ian Stewart.

On Qish wormholes are grown in matched pairs by various plants and creatures.  But potential and kinetic energy are strictly conserved; to enter a wormhole whose endpoint is at a location with greater gravitational potential energy (i.e. higher) requires supplying the necessary energy.  A passage that loses potential energy will be accompanied by a commensurate gain of kinetic energy.  Similarly with kinetic energy; moving away from the equator results in leaving a wormhole with excess kinetic energy due to the difference in angular velocity.

This is worked out in a number of different circumstances.  For example, a pair of wormholes, entrances facing out, can be placed over someone's neck so that their head can be dislocated from their body.  But if the head is raised too far above the body, blood pressure will not be enough to cross the potential energy difference to the head.

In another case, an animal will hunt by placing one end of a wormhole facing up on an elevated surface, and the other facing down on top of a pond in which it hides.  The upper wormhole will thus appear to be a pool of water.  An animal that attempts to drink will start to pass through the portal, and the ensuing conversion of potential to kinetic energy will suck the victim through the portal into the pond.

Comment: As for time travel, Sawyer's *Starplex* uses mass moved from the future to the present to reduce the rate of expansion of the universe so it will start to collapse.

Answer (score 5):

The Portal computer games implemented momentum-through-portals, and interacting with and exploiting these physics is a key part of the gameplay experience.

Notable aspects of portal-momentum explored during play include gravitational momentum-pumping (put a portal in the ceiling above one in the floor and pick up more momentum each time you drop through) and launching from an angled surface by putting one portal onto the surface and the other down a pit, then dropping into the pit.

Comment: This seems to be rather the opposite of conservation of momentum, no?

Comment: @DavidW: Your momentum *in your own frame* is conserved as you pass through the portal: If you drop feet first through a portal in the floor, you come out of the ceiling feet first with the same downward velocity. For the angled-surface launch, you drop into the floor with some velocity, and come out of the surface with the same velocity normal to the surface. Other than when passing through portals, you are subject to standard gravity, and the ceiling/floor trick highlights one of the fundamental physics problems with portals: they break *global* conservation of momentum laws.

Comment: Slight correction to my final sentence above: The angled-surface launch is the effect that illustrates local/global incompatibility of momentum through portals (or, if you define physics such that the outbound portal gets an impulse kick for redirecting momentum a violation of action/reaction pairing, as the object transiting the portal doesn’t feel the kick). The floor/ceiling trick breaks conservation of energy within what is otherwise a potential field.

Answer (score 4):

E. E. "Doc" Smith's Lensman series, while not dealing with teleportation, but rather inertialess travel (called "free" travel in his books) has his spaceships matching intrinsic velocities with objects that they are interacting with upon resuming inertial flight (called "inert").

The "free" ships maintain the intrinsic velocity of the object they just left - usually a planet orbiting a star, so when they approach another planet, they stand off a distance and manually work out the relative velocities and match them so that they don't accidentally have a high-speed collision with the object when returning to inert travel.

Exactly how this is done is glossed over in the books, usually described similarly to the quote below (from First Lensman, Edward E. Smith, Pyramid Books, 1968):

> The Chief Pilot was now at work, with all the virtuoso's skill of his rank and grade; one of the hall-marks of which is to make difficult tasks look easy. He played trills and runs and arpeggios—at times veritable glissades—upon keyboards and pedals, directing with micrometric precision the tremendous forces of the superdreadnaught to the task of matching the intrinsic velocity of New York Spaceport at the time of his departure to the I. V. of the surface of the planet so far below.

Occasionally objects and people are transferred between "Free" ships and put into the "Cocoon" which is a highly sprung armored room (from Second Stage Lensman, Edward E. Smith, Astounding Science Fiction November 1941-Feburary 1942):

> Kinnison wrapped the package in heavy gauze, then in roll after roll of spring steel mesh. He jammed heavy steel springs into the ends, then clamped the whole thing into a form with tool-steel bolts an inch in diameter. He poured in two hundred pounds of metallic mercury, filling the form to the top. Then a cover, also bolted on. This whole assembly went into the "cocoon," a cushioned, heavily padded affair suspended from all four walls, ceiling, and floor by every shock-absorbing device known to the engineers of the Patrol.
>
> The Dauntless inerted briefly at Kinnison's word and it seemed as though a troop of elephants were running silently amuck in the cocoon room. The package to be inerted weighed no more than eight ounces—but eight ounces of mass, at a relative velocity of fifty miles per second, possesses a kinetic energy by no means to be despised.

How people would cope with this is never mentioned, but it doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: This is also an aspect of FTL travel in Vinge's *Zone of Thought* universe and becomes plot-relevant in *A Fire Upon the Deep*.

Comment: @DavidW Vinge also wrote a novel, _The Witling_, which explored the consequences of teleporting from one part of a planet to another, or teleporting air masses from one part of a planet to another (that turns out to be a pretty effective weapon).

Comment: @user888379 Kevin O'Donnell Jr. did something similar in his *The Journeys of McGill Feighan* series, using teleported air as a weapon.  (Among other inventive ways of using teleportation as a weapon.)

Comment: Actually, how people cope with this is mentioned in the series. There is a cocoon for living beings, but it is only used when the relative inertial velocity is much smaller. Doctor Lacy and Clarrissa MacDougall go through the process. (*Galactic Patrol*, chapter 17).

Comment: @EvilSnack I was meaning in terms of coping physically with the acceleration changes. I was aware of the use in *Galactic Patrol*, just didn't see any mention of small relative velocity, just the need to do it before many changes in relative velocity take place - it does mention extra padding though.

Answer (score 3):

Considered fairly carefully in the *Night's Dawn* trilogy by Peter F Hamilton. Adamist starships can jump multiple light years at a time, but retain their velocity relative to the universe so need to spend time realigning their vector and speed to account for galactic rotation and local motion of their destination.

*Reality Dysfunction*:

> While the bitek craft could tailor their wormholes to produce a
> terminus at the required location irrespective of their orbit and
> acceleration vector, ships like the Lady Macbeth jumped along their
> orbital track without any leeway at all. It was that limitation which
> cost captains a great deal of time between jumps. The starship had to
> align itself directly on its target star. In interstellar space it
> wasn’t so difficult, simply a question of adjusting for natural error.
> But the initial jump out of a star system had to be as accurate as
> humanly possible to prevent emergence point inaccuracies from growing
> out of hand. If a starship was departing an asteroid that was heading
> away from its next port of call, the captain could spend days
> reversing his orbit, and the cost in delta-V reserve was horrendous.

The Naked God:

> Earth’s sun orbits the galactic centre roughly once every two hundred
> and thirty million years, giving it an approximate velocity of two
> hundred and twenty kilometres per second relative to the core. Other
> stars, of course, have different orbital velocities, depending on
> their distance from the core, so their velocities relative to each
> other are also different.
>
> [...]
>
> The ZTT jump might provide a short cut
> across the interstellar gulf, but it cannot magically change inertia.
> A starship emerging from a jump has precisely the same vector it had
> when it started. In order to rendezvous with the planet or asteroid at
> its destination, its delta-v has to be altered to match. It’s a
> tedious process which uses up plenty of fuel;

Comment: I can see one problem with ZTT: **WHY** inertia is a thing in wormhole transition. Haven't read it, and quick internet search brings no answer to that question, but physics are somewhat straightforward in this: if you leave one dimension in one place, enter another dimension and then reenter original dimension, inertia (as well as a slew of other things) just... leaves the equation. Of course, since interdimensional travel is not something we can observe, it's all guessing, but still. Physics showed few times already that sometimes it works differently, but for time being logic and math rule..

Answer (score 2):

Poul Anderson brings this up in *World Without Stars* (aka *The Ancient Gods*), noting that coming out of hyperdrive can leave you with a sizeable amount of relative velocity to correct, especially if you make an instantaneous jump to a distant galaxy where the differnce might be a considerable proportion of c.